# Metrics for Covid19 time series

Tags: time-series

I have daily observations of Covid19 data for many countries. More specifically, I have daily observations about new_cases,total_cases,new_deaths,total_deaths,reproduction_rate,stringency_index (represents the stringency of government measures during the Covid19 pandemic) for every country. So, I have 6 times series for every country of my dataset. I want to find some metrics for every variable of my dataset so that these metrics "replace" every variable of my dataset. I will give an example to make it more clear. Let's suppose that I want to "replace" new cases with i.e 3 metrics (metric1,metric2,metric3). I want to find a metric1,a metric2, a metric3 so that when I have the time series of new_cases of a country metric1 will give me 1 value, metric2 will give me 1 value and metric3 will give me 1 value.